Weasyprint dependency 'gobject-2.0-0' installation error on Railway.app
I am using this Dockerfile configuration for my django project
FROM python:3.12.2-slim-bullseye

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    python3-cffi \
    python3-brotli \
    libpango1.0-0 \
    libpangoft2-1.0-0 \
    libharfbuzz-subset0 \
    libffi-dev \
    libcairo2 \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev \
    libgobject-2.0-0 \
    libgobject2.0-dev \
    build-essential \
    && apt-get clean

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /PAQSBackend

# Copy the application code
COPY . /PAQSBackend/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY PAQSBackend.wsgi /PAQSBackend/PAQSBackend.wsgi
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "PAQSBackend.wsgi"]

The build and deployment runs fine. However, when I run the project, I get this error message

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 827, in loadbackend_lib
raise OSError(msg)
OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': gobject-2.0-0: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory. Additionally,
ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called
'gobject-2.0-0'

I would want to know what is actually happening and also how to resolve this. I only face this issue when I am deploying it on Railway.app
